# Moduli of parabolic bundles of rank two on ℙ¹

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the structure of Moduli space of rank two parabolic bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$, of degree zero or degree one, with weights $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\dotsc\frac{1}{2})$ at $n$ points, say  $n$ is even. For very small weights, the moduli space is a GIT quotient $((\mathbb{P}^1)^n)^\text{ss}/SL_2$, by a paper of Moon–Yoo.  Can the above half weight-case be written as an explicit blow-up, blow-down of the quotient $((\mathbb{P}^1)^n)^\text{ss}/\operatorname{SL}_2$?

Answer (score 1):

The space you are interested in, call it $M_{(\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{2})}$, can be described as a small transformation of the blow-up $X^{n-3}_n$ of $\mathbb{P}^{n-3}$ at $n$ points in linear general position.

More specifically, $X^{n-3}_n$ is a Mori dream space. So its movable cone has a decomposition in convex chambers which are the nef cones of all the possibile small transfomations of $X^{n-3}_n$. From the GIT poit of view going from one chamber to the other corresponds to changing the stability conditions that is changing the weights.

The space $M_{(\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{2})}$ is a Fano variety of dimension $n−3$, which is smooth if $n$ is odd, and has isolated singularities if $n$ is even. From the point of view of the above decomposition its nef cone (when $n$ is odd) is the chamber containing the anticanonical divisor of $X^{n-3}_n$.

For $n$ even the anticanonical divisor of $X^{n-3}_n$ lies in the intersection of several walls. From the birational point of view this means that $M_{(\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{2})}$ is not $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial. From the GIT point of view it means that there are strictly semistable points.

For details you may look at:

- S. Mukai, *Finite generation of the Nagata invariant rings in A-D-E cases*, RIMS Preprint n. 1502, Kyoto, 2005.
- C. Casagrande, *Rank 2 quasiparabolic vector bundles on P1 and the variety of linear subspaces contained in two odd-dimensional quadrics*, Mathematische Zeitschrift volume 280, 981–988 (2015).
- C. Araujo and C. Casagrande,
  *On the Fano variety of linear spaces contained in two odd-dimensional quadrics*, Geometry & Topology 21 (2017) 3009–3045.

Comment: thanks..could this be made more precise,i.e.  is $M_{1/2,...1/2}$ a blow down of $X^{n-3}_n$, along a variety $S$, and what is $S$ ?

Comment: No, it is not a blow down. There is a birational map between the two which is an isomorphism in condimension one. You have to flip several subvarieties of $X_n^{n-3}$ to reach $M_{(\frac{1}{2},\dots,frac{1}{2})}$. These subvarities are basically cones over secant varieties of the degree $n-3$ rational curve through the $n$ blownup points. I will add some references in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and references.